# How to run Eclipse with java 8 temporarily so as to install jboss adaptor?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I want to install jboss adaptor to Eclipse, but according to the answers as below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262682/eclipse-mars-not-showing-jboss-server

I need to run eclipse with java 8

But I don't want to use java 8 now, so can I just run Eclipse with java 8 temporarily  so as to install jboss adaptor and then return to java 7?

if so, how to do so?  currently I have not installed java 8, what steps should I follow? thanks

I'm using linux

Comment: [Using Multiple Versions of JDK and Eclipse in Single Machine](https://dzone.com/articles/using-multiple-versions-jdk)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, but I'm using linux, not windows.

Comment: A similar approach should work on Linux ...